# Image layout broken when SE site not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, 500-server-error

Image layout broken when SE site not found

This is the "not found" error page for [Foobar SE](http://foobar.stackexchange.com). Something is wrong with the CSS or image size right at the bottom.

[image: image overlaps with footer bar; footer contents overlap with image]

Comment: What browser / version?  Looks fine in IE9.

Comment: I'm using Safari 5.0.2

Comment: @jadarnel27 Occurs in Chrome when viewport is too small. Works properly in IE8 and FF3.6-win32 - Looks like its a WebKit problem

Comment: No repro with FF9.

Comment: So it's because the window/screen was too small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout for the site-not-found page has been updated with the new theme, and this bug was fixed in the process. Thanks for the report.